# How does human eye perceive distances?

Tags: optics, visible-light, lenses, vision, perception

In case of myopia a parallel beam of light appears to come from the far point of the eye when we use corrective concave lenses. But we do not perceive it as it is coming from the far point, instead we feel it coming from its source. This is not how we perceive image formation by a plane mirror. In the case of a plane mirror we produce the reflected rays backwards to make them converge at a point behind the mirror and we perceive that light is coming from that point behind the mirror.

So what is the reason for this? How do we perceive distances?

Comment: read up on parallax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do animal perceive distances with their eyes and ears](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8569/)

Answer (score 2):

For people with normal vision in both eyes, distance is perceived when the brain interprets the eye turning angle required to focus both eyes on a distant object. For close objects, the turn angle is large and for distant objects the turn angle is small. This effect is called *parallax* and relies on the horizontal separation of the two eyes, which in turn requires a turning angle to converge their images into one.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to niels nielsen's correct answer, the brain is an *amazing* pattern recognition device.  We also take hints from the environment, both visual and otherwise (aural, tactile, etc.).  We develop this skill over years as a young child.

The brain fuses these senses as needed, because none of them are perfect.  The [Ames Room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ames_room), for instance is very good at fooling our brain's assumption that walls that look like they meet at 90 degree angles do, in fact, meet at 90 degrees.  This particular illusion is spoiled by parallax, which is why the Ames room typically gives you a single peephole to look into the room with.  Other illusions are very good at fooling our sense of parallax.  There's an easy to reproduce trick known as the [Finger Sausage Illusion](http://amagicclassroom.com/uploads/3/4/5/2/34528828/finger_sausage_illusion.pdf) which makes it appear as though there is a small floating "sausage" between your fingers as the brain has a hard time fusing the images of the two eyes together. (such fusion is required for parallax detection to work)